# forward variable to php script on button click

Tags: php, html, button

I have this HTML button:

```
<form action="testscript.php" name ="more" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="More Details">
</form>
```

Which when clicked runs this PHP script:

```
<?php echo 'button pushed: ';
echo $buttonvalue;
?>
```

My question is, how to I assign a value to the button so that when its clicked it will forward its value ($buttonvalue) to the PHP script

For example when the button is clicked i want it to run the script and the result should be button pushed: blue

How do i assign "blue" to the button?

Comment: Use a hidden input in your form instead, then use `$_GET` superglobal to access the value.

Comment: thanks, this is what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

HTML :

```
<form action="testscript.php" name ="more" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="buttonvalue" value="Some Value">
    <input type="submit" value="More Details">
</form>
```

PHP :

```
<?php 
echo 'button pushed: ';
echo !empty($_GET['buttonvalue']) ? $_GET['buttonvalue'] : '';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. works perfectly. Now i just need to adapt it my actual code :)

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tag with 'btn' class. And pass value to next page with id.

Page 1.

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="next-page.php?id=value">Click me</a>
```

Page 2.

```
 $buttonvalue = $_GET['id'];
echo $buttonvalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="testscript.php" name ="more" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="getDataName" value="123">
  <input type="submit" value="More Details">
</form>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php 
   $buttonvalue= isset ($_GET['getDataName']) ? $_GET['getDataName'] : '';
   if(!empty($buttonvalue)){
    echo 'button pushed: ';
    echo $buttonvalue;
   }else{
    echo 'button not pushed: ';
   }
?>
```